# Netty vs Grizzly detailed differences

Tags: http, netty, nio, grizzly

Looking for differences between these two. The most information i was able to find is about performance. Netty has much better community for sure they also a little differentiate in transport protcols. The question is when should i choose first over second? What else differentiate them? What can I do in Netty which I couldn't in Grizzly and vice versa? My main goal is using it for Http